# What are the Device Filters?

Tags: asp.net, filter, tags, device, prefix

I always get this Error when I mistype a tag in an aspx file:

"Unrecognized tag prefix or device filter"

I know what tag prefix is , but I don't have good information about Device Filters.

Can any one help me find a comprehensive resource to learn about this topic because I looked it up on the internet and I found the Microsoft website which had only excerpts and no examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this:

"Using device filters, applications can customize the appearance of controls for specific hardware devices or for categories of devices. The customization is based on the capabilities of the hardware device being used to browse the application...."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4a28z6x5(v=vs.80).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ffa7b0h(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Or a more up-to-date starting point: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178620.aspx, although it then fails to talk about how you define them ;)

Comment: I was asking for  information like: what device filter keyword should I use to identify for example the device's screen size, and accordingly choose the suitable menu. but thanks for your help Oscar :) and Zhaph-Ben Duguid